# Will calling your file .html work even if you have embedded php?

Tags: php, html, safari

Safari is playing up and not reading .php files it will only read html. Wonder if calling .php would work?

Comment: PHP parts only execute with a webserver configured for that. Do you invoke your files over an http:// URL and with a server, or just as local files:// ?

Comment: In what sense? Do you directly open the PHP file or obtain it from a server? If you open it directly, it won't parse it for you. That's the purpose of the PHP interpeter on the server.

Comment: Safari doesn't mind about extensions. None of the browsers do. You could even create a file called index.jake for all your browser cares, as long as it contains HTML content. The problem is probably on the server-side.

Comment: sorted, i found the problem it was the text editor i was using but thanks anyway guys.

Comment: @Oldskool, what I think H2CO3 meant was "are you opening the file from your local filesystem or browsing to it on your webserver?" Obviously, Safari isn't going to invoke PHP itself in order to parse the contents, so simply renaming a .php file to .html will not allow you to open it without running it through an interpreter first (either command-line or via webserver).

Answer (score 3):

Generally this is not a good idea, but it can be accomplished by telling your webserver that all files with a `.html` extension are to be processed by PHP. How to do so depends on your webserver.

It adds overhead to non-PHP files that have the `.html` extension, causing PHP to be invoked and search for PHP tags even when there are none.

Comment: Check my second paragraph. Again, it's better to fix the problem that to burden the server with a workaround.

Comment: yeah i can call the file .php again and it will work thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no.  You can make it work by updating your .htaccess file.  Just add this: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` and it may work depending on how your server is working.  I would also check http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/php-in-html-files.html to see some more examples of how you could do that if the above code doesn't work with your server.